# Inverse of $f(x) = (2x-\pi)^3 + 2x - \cos x$ at $x=\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $f(x) = (2x-\pi)^3 + 2x - \cos x\;.\; $Then the value of $\displaystyle \frac{d(f^{-1}(x)}{dx}$ at $x = \pi$ is

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Let $g(x) = f^{-1}(x)\;,$ Then we have to find $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}(g(x))=g'(x)$ at $x=\pi.$

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are Inverse of each other , Then Using the formula $f(g(x)) = g(f(x)) = x$.

Now Differentiate both side w. r to $x\;,$ We Get

$\displaystyle f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x) = g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x) = 1\Rightarrow g'(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}................(1)$

Now put $\displaystyle x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ in $f(x)\;,$ we get $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\pi.$ and $f'(x)=6(2x-\pi)^2+2$ and

$\displaystyle f'\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 2$

Now put $\displaystyle x= \frac{\pi}{2}$ in eqn...$(1)\;,$ we get $\displaystyle g'\left(f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{f'\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\Rightarrow g'(\pi)=\frac{1}{2}$

Is my solution and process is Right, If not then how can we solve it

Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is fine until the step: $f'(\pi/2) = 2$ while it is $3$ since $f'(x) = 6(2x-\pi)^2 + 2 + \sin x \to f'(\pi/2) = 2+\sin(\pi/2) = 3$. So the right answer should be $\dfrac{1}{3}$.